# When two normal distributions have same mean and variance, can they be independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, normal-distribution, expected-value

Actually, I was wondering if we say x,y ~ N(2;2), then can we say X=Y.
Also, what would be the value of E[xy].
I need to calculate E[xy] and the only information given is x,y ~ N(2,2). Can we do it without assuming that x and y are independent?

Options are 2, 4, 8, 16.

Comment: $X$ is equal to $Y$ *in distribution* only. For calculating $E(XY)$, we need the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. Saying $X,Y\sim N(,)$ does not specify the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. Neither does it say anything about dependence/independence.

Comment: A quick comment about the title, in case it helps clarify things: Independence is a property of random variables, not of distributions.

Comment: You do not have enough information to calculate $E[xy]$. All you can say with what you have is that, by Cauchy-Schwarz, $|E[xy]| \leq \sqrt{E[x^2]E[y^2]}$

Comment: Is it a multiple-choice question? What are the other options? Maybe the others can be eliminated. Can you edit your question to list the options?

Comment: @Bungo options were 2, 4, 8, 16. Can we assume x and y independent if nothing else is given? Or could it be something else? None of these was not an option, my bad.

Comment: @Pandey If this is the exact question you have quoted, then without any additional context, it is a bad question.

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes it is exactly the same. They must have made some mistake them. In any case, should we assume x and y are independent?

Comment: @Pandey Why? If we are hell bent on getting an answer to an incorrectly posed question, then we can assume whatever we want.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not say that X=Y. That would mean the value of X is always equal to the value of Y. Consider this example : imagine that you pick two people in the population . X is the number of children of the first one and Y is the number of children of the second one. Both random variables have the same probability but are not the same. If you learn that X is 1, then you can not conclude that Y is 1 too.

In your case, X and Y have the same marginal probabilities but They can be : totally independent, lightly or strongly dependent or even be the same random variable (X=Y).

A system of 2 random variables is not entirely defined by the marginal probabilities of each variable ($N(2,2)$ in your case). To fully define it, you need the density of probability over (X,Y) : p(x,y) a function of two variables that integrates to 1. In your case, you have only the sum of this function on the 2 dimensions x and y. So you can not calculate $E[xy]=\int{p(x,y).xy.dx.dy}$

Comment: I was asked to calculate E[xy] and the only information which was given is x,y ~ N(2,2). How can we solve this question?

Comment: @Pandey We cannot.